# Joomla 3 call model function inside controller

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I want to call a function from model inside controller

my model : httpdocs/components/com_storemanager/models/searchmanager.php

```
<?php

/**
 * @version    CVS: 1.0.2
 * @package    Com_storemanager
 * @author     LYT
 * @copyright  2017 LYT
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

jimport('joomla.application.component.modellist');

/**
 * Methods supporting a list of storemanager records.
 *
 * @since  1.6
 */
class storemanagerModelSearchmanager extends JModelItem
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct ();
    }

    /**
     * Method to auto-populate the model state.
     *
     * Note. Calling getState in this method will result in recursion.
     *
     * @return void
     *
     * @since    1.6
     *
     */
    public function managerList($name) 
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select($db->qn("title"))  
            ->from($db->qn("jos_storemanager_manager"))
            ->where($db->quoteName('manager') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('\''.$name.'.%\''));


        return $db->setQuery($query)->loadObjectList(); 
    }

}
```

I did try this inside my controller : 
/httpdocs/components/com_storemanager/controller.php

```
function searchmanager()
    {
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $name = $jinput->get('name');

        $managers = $this->getModel( 'Searchmanager' , 'Model' )->managerList($name);

        foreach($managers as $manager) 
        {
            echo '<br><h3>'.$manger->title . '</h3>';
        }

        exit;
    }
```

but no result;

I tried all solutions

```
require_once JPATH_COMPONENT_SITE.'/models/searchmanager.php'; 

    $tags_model = JModelLegacy::getInstance( 'Searchmanager', 'searchmanager' );
$tags_model->managerList($name);
```

Not working

```
$model = $this->getModel() ;
$articles = $model->managerList($name);
```

This one too not working

Comment: I need to bring up that your WHERE clause is not constructed in alignment with Joomla's advice on security. https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22712/12352 At the moment, you are single-quoting the string twice. Since you are only checking from the start of the column value, you might perfer this simpler alternative: [LOCATE()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-locate-function.php) ...written as `->where("LOCATE(" . $db->q($name) . ", manager) = 1");`  To help you debug, use the `enqueueMessage()` lines from https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24161/12352

Comment: I am commenting this advice because I don't know if fixing this one thing will solve the whole problem.  If it does, I am happy to transfer to an answer.

Comment: Also, replace the prefix you've got `jos_` with `#__`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this piece of code in my controller to access the model.

```
    JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'components' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'com_' . $feature . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'models');
    $model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Items', 'InventoryModel');
```

That is cut and pasted straight out of a working piece of code, no edits so I expect it should work for you if you change the code around com_ . $feature and whats inside the the getInstance brackets.

Comment: To implement the DRY coding principle (which pleasantly reduces horizontal scrolling), you might consider declaring an array of directory names and glue them together with `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ` like this: https://3v4l.org/cIrLP

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks for the suggestion. I agree about the horizontal scroll. I use similar code in a few places so I will have a look if I can use your code to reduce things elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I originally posted this as a comment, but advice that may resolve the issue must be posted as an answer.  I will hedge my post and state that there may be additional problems beyond what I am addressing.  See irata's answer for the possible MVC fix.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select($db->qn("title"))  
    ->from($db->qn("#__storemanager_manager"))
    ->where("LOCATE(" . $db->quote($name) . ", " . $db->quoteName(manager) . ") = 1");

JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($query->dump(), 'info');  // don't show your rendered query to the public
try {
    return $db->setQuery($query)->loadObjectList();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Query Syntax Error: " . $e->getMessage(), 'error');  // don't show $e->getMessage() to public
}
```

The adjustment to the WHERE clause still requires qualifying rows to have a `manager` value that begins with the value held in `$name`.

I have included two `enqueueMessage()` calls to help you to debug, but you must remove them when you are finished the dev stage.

Please read https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22712/12352 regarding your LIKE syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed for someone if he get the same error by using 
My Model : 
/httpdocs/components/com_storemanager/models/searchmanager.php

```
<?php

    defined('_JEXEC') or die;

    jimport('joomla.application.component.modellist');

    /**
     * Methods supporting a list of Hpj_storemanager records.
     *
     * @since  1.6
     */
    class storemanagerModelSearchmanager extends JModelItem
    {

        /**
         * Method to auto-populate the model state.
         *
         * Note. Calling getState in this method will result in recursion.
         *
         * @return void
         *
         * @since    1.6
         *
         */
        public function managerList($name) 
        {
            $db = JFactory::getDBO();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->select($db->qn("title"))  
                ->from($db->qn("#__storemanager_manager"))
                ->where("LOCATE(" . $db->quote($name) . ", " . $db->quoteName("manager") . ") = 1");

            JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($query->dump(), 'info');  // don't show your rendered query to the public
            try {
                return $db->setQuery($query)->loadObjectList();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Query Syntax Error: " . $e->getMessage(), 'error');  // don't show $e->getMessage() to public
            }

        }

    }
```

And in my Controller : /httpdocs/components/com_storemanager/controller.php

```
function searchmanager()
    {
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

        $name = $jinput->get('text'));

        $model = $this->getModel('Searchmanager');

        $manegers = $model->managerList($name)

        foreach($managers as $manager) 
        {
            echo '<br><h3>'.$manager->title.'</h3><p>';
        }

        exit;
    }
```

Comment: While this may give you the desired result, it is in breach of the MVC design model to print anything from the Controller -- a View is where printing should occur.  When I suggested `loadObjectList()` it was to allow the addition of other columns in the result set.  However, if you are only extracting one column, the best method would be `loadColumn()` which will generate a 1-dimensional (indexed) array.  This will allow reduced syntax while looping through the results.  `exit` should not be necessary. You have a typo @ `$manegers`. What is your view directory structure?